# Task continuation with context "use_current" does not work

Tags: c++, visual-c++, windows-8, windows-runtime, ppl

I have tried looking for answer to this since three days back. It is either I have done something fundamentally wrong (that there's an obvious mistake) or the thing is too new to have any references, I can't seem to figure why simple cases like this would fail.

The following code uses PPL task library in C++ in a Windows Store application, simulating a file loading operation that takes 2 seconds before breaking out of the loop (of course this is to illustrate the problem with minimal codes, the real loop does other rendering to show progress, too).

The continuation part of the code (i.e. "fileLoaded = true") never gets called if I use "use_current" as the continuation context:

```
bool fileLoaded = false;
while (!fileLoaded)
{
    concurrency::task<void>([this]()
    {
        // Simulate file load delay
        concurrency::wait(2000);

    }).then([this, &fileLoaded]()
    {
        fileLoaded = true; // This never gets executed!

        // If the following is changed to "use_default" or 
        // "use_arbitrary", then this continuation gets called.
    }, concurrency::task_continuation_context::use_current());

    concurrency::wait(50);
}
```

The same code works if I use "use_default" or "use_arbitrary", and properly set "fileLoad" to "true". This code can be placed anywhere in a Windows Store C++ app (e.g. Direct2D app), and it would fail (I have placed it in "DirectXPage::DirectXPage" constructor body, which I expect it to be the main UI thread). Did I do something horribly wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are calling `.then()` on the UI thread, `use_current()` will cause the continuation to be scheduled for execution on the UI thread.

However, that continuation cannot run until the UI thread is free (i.e., when it is not doing any work).  But, in your example, the UI thread is never free:  the `DirectXPage` constructor is running on the UI thread.  The `DirectXPage` constructor will not return until the continuation executes and the continuation cannot execute until the `DirectXPage` constructor returns.

You need to allow the constructor to return so that the UI thread is free to do other work (like execute the continuation).

---

Also note that if you are using `fileLoaded` for cross-thread communication, you need to use an `std::atomic<bool>` or some other proper synchronization object.  A simple `bool` is insufficient for synchronization.

Comment: Thanks James, that sounds like a good explanation for it (I will mark it as an answer soon, since I still have the following doubts):

In my head a thread is always "alive", since it cannot return to the caller which created it (otherwise the thread will be considered "terminated"). In order to stay "alive", it needs to either be in a long running loop, or waiting for a synchronization object (e.g. mutex).

... (continue below)

Comment: If the above understanding is true, then "use_current" is something that makes use of another "construct" that only UI thread in Windows Store App has (i.e. UI thread must be having some "gap" or "pause" that allows for "returning thread to execute in its context"). And a regular "naïve big looping background thread" does not have such "construct", therefore "use_current" will not be possible for them. Is that understanding correct? :)

Comment: Correct:  the UI thread has [a message queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927.aspx).  In a traditional Windows ("desktop") application, there will be a loop that pumps messages and dispatches them.  In a Windows Store app, this pumping occurs in the Windows Runtime app framework code.  When you tell the PPL to continue in the UI thread context using `use_current()`, a message will be sent to the UI thread when the continuation is ready to be run.  When the UI thread pumps this message, it will be dispatched and the continuation will run.

Comment: Thanks James, that explains everything I needed to know. :)

P/S: Good point about that "atomic" part, I have always been thinking that in native languages like C++, setting of a primitive value (as long as it can be done in one CPU cycle) is always atomic? I may be wrong, just for safety I’ll go ahead and use "atomic<bool>".

Comment: @BenGoh:  There is no guarantee that a write to a primitive object is atomic.  On some architectures (x86/x64 included), reads and writes to small, aligned objects are atomic.  However, atomicity is not the only problem here:  if you do not tell the compiler that an object is going to be modified by multiple threads, it is free to generate code that is incorrect if multiple threads attempt to modify that object. For example, it could (and _will_ in some circumstances) generate code such that the UI thread reads `fileLoaded` once and caches that value and never reads from `fileLoaded` again.

Comment: @BenGoh:  (In this particular case, it would be unlikely that this optimization would be made, but it is possible in other, similar cases.)  If you access an object from multiple threads and at least one of those threads may modify the object, you must synchronize access to the object, for example, by using `atomic<T>`, `mutex`, or some other synchronization primitive.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed explanation, James! Things surely have evolved since the good old days. I have a note to self to always use atomic<T> across threads, regardless of how small a primitive is :)